# Significance of 'in' 'out' and 'retval' inside parameters in C#

Tags: c#, parameters

```
Output([out, retval] long* Retval);
Length([in] long Len);
```

What is the significance of 'out', 'retval' and 'in' in this case ??

I know the significance of ref and out which is used usually, but not this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more context on this code?

Comment: This is not C# code; it's probably IDL

Answer (score 1):

I found the following information regarding classes generated for COM interop:

> By default, the .NET Framework
>   provides an automatic mapping between
>   the two styles of exception handling
>   for COM interface methods called by
>   the .NET Framework.
>
> - The return value changes to the signature of the parameter marked
>     retval (void if the method has no
>     parameter marked as retval).
> - The parameter marked as retval is left off of the argument list of the
>     method.

You can find more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

These attributes are used for COM integration, they don't change the way these methods work in C#.